# Screws too loose on PSU

Tags: power-supply, screws

I have an older ATX PSU that for some reason has larger mounting screw holes than usual. (Maybe someone tried forcing larger screws at some point and stripped them?) The holes are now too loose. Is there some way to tighten the fit again? Can I wrap the screws in plumber's tape or something? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right size screws?

Comment: Yes, they fit snug in another PSU. I have collected dozens of them over the years building PCs.

Comment: PSU manufacturers have been known to use non-standard parts

Comment: The PSU came pre-installed in my Rosewill case, so the problem may have occurred during assembly.

Comment: Use larger screws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blue Loctite](https://www.henkel-adhesives.com/us/en/products/industrial-adhesives/threadlockers.html#sb-Red-or-Blue-How-to-Choose-a-LOCTITE-Threadlocker-4) is your friend, although plumber's tape is  not a bad idea and [considered harmless to ingest](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94619/is-teflon-a-poison-if-ingested).

Comment: Is Loctite permanent or can it be easily removed?

Comment: Removable. Frequently used on Modern Sporting Rifles.